# Why are annotations preferred over deployment descriptors in Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee

With deployment descriptors I can easily configure the beans and other servlet information during deployment without the need to open the code and compile it again.

Then why annotations replaced the deployment descriptors, annotations are followed in spring, JSF 2.0 and hibernate too.

Can any one tell me the main advantages of annotations over deployment descriptors and other config files like( beans.xml, spring-config.xml, struts.xml)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there's a trend to replace a kind of *dual language programming* (Java + XML) with only one (Java).

And it is sometimes true - it's easy to analyze and prototype an application, when everything (data, methods and metadata/annotations) are in one place.

But there's also hidden truth. XML has it's use and in Spring there's a kind of XML DSL - dedicated XML tags/attributes to configure particular aspects of application (Security, MVC, Transaction configuration, AOP). And using this it's **much** easier to write and (what's more important) read and maintain such configuration.

And one, sometimes forgotten aspect. With XML you can have two objects of the same class configured differently. With annotations, you put them **on** the class, so every object of such class is generally the same.

Comment: If annotations are used we need to recompile the code for every small changes in the class. That is not needed in many cases if we have the information in xml. Does annotion type provide any solution for this. Please Help.

Comment: Yes. Changing annotations requires the recompilation and I'm not sure there's solution to this. But changing XML is not that easy as it seem - XMLs are usually packaged in JARs and/or put into WEB-INF of WAR applications, so it also may require some or all steps of the build process.